# pyspark on windows - error launching

Tags: python, installation, pyspark

I am posting this to help others with the same problem as I was not able to solve it by searching myself.

I was getting this error after following installation instructions:

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: "Error while instantiating 'org.apac
he.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"

SOLVED:  The problem for me was that the winutils.exe file was not in the correct folder (it was in the HADOOP_HOME root rather than within the bin subdirectory).

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: When you created this question there was a check mark at the bottom that said "Answer my own question." You should have done that- post the question and answer yourself to share the knowledge.

Comment: You still can do this. Simply edit the question and post your answer as an, err, answer.